# Getting a list of possible generic types from an ambiguous new declaration

Tags: c#, generics, roslyn

I'm currently trying to understand Roslyn's handling of generic types using GetSymbolInfo. It seems to me that if I am ambiguous about the generic type that I am going to use, I should get a list of CandidateSymbols, but this is not the case. Here is some test code:

```
[Test]
public void Test_Generic_Type_Ambiguous_Resolution()
{
    string code = @"using System;
namespace Test
{
    public class A<T1>
    {}

    public class A<T1,T2>
    {}

    public class B
    {
        public void Body()
        {
            var test = new A<
        }
    }
}";
    var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
    var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("test")
        .AddSyntaxTrees(tree);

    var newA = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<GenericNameSyntax>().First();
    var symbol = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree).GetSymbolInfo(newA);

    //This is false, no candidate symbols but an exact match on A<T1>
    Assert.That(symbol.CandidateSymbols.Length > 0 && symbol.Symbol == null);
}
```

Instead, it seems that it matches on the type with the least type arguments. What is the correct way to get all the available types in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all available types named "A" at the location, what you should be doing is calling `LookupSymbols`, like so:

```
var symbols = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree).LookupSymbols(newA.Span.Start, name: "A");
```

I think why you're not getting the candidate symbols you expect there is because the compiler isn't treating that as ambiguous. Rather, it's taking your A<, adding a > implicitly, and then binding it as a generic name with arity 1.

Comment: There is something called recommendation service, but its internal. @jasonmalinowski isn't that what OP is looking for?